# MkdirAll permission does not fit with linux permissions

Tags: linux, go, permissions, filesystems

I use Go (golang) 1.14 on Ubuntu 18.04

the files arrange like this:
*parent/* , and it is the working directory.

when i use

```
os.MkdirAll("dir/subdir", 0777)
```

it does make the files looks like
parent/dir/subdir

but the file permission of dir is
`drwxrwxr-x` and not `drwxrwxrwx` as i expected.
with 0666 permissions, i get permission denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `umask` for Ubuntu is:

```
# umask

0002
```

so it will remove the `w` user-permissions from your `mkdir`s permissions.

Unset this, and your program should get the permissions you desire:

```
# umask 0

# go build -o mkd ./main.go && ./mkd

$ ls -al dir/

drwxrwxrwx 3 me me 4096 Mar 17 10:27 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 me me 4096 Mar 17 10:27 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 me me 4096 Mar 17 10:27 subdir
```

---

**Note:** If you want to ensure you don't tamper with the umask and only do this for your exe, use the sub-shell technique:

```
# (umask 0 && ./mkd)
```

or launch via a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd `dirname "$0"`
umask 0
./mkd $*      # <- passes along any arguments
```

Comment: Yes, correct.

Read this as well: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15210